# Servlet. Specification of Mappings?

Tags: java, tomcat, url-routing

Based on `Java Servlet Specification Version 3.0`:

In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:

A string beginning with a '/' character and ending with '/*' suffix is used for path mapping.

A string beginning with '*.' prefix is used as an extension mapping.

A string containing only the '/' character indicates the "default" servlet of the application.

All other strings are used for exact matches only.

so, I have next questions:

1. How I can process this URL pattern: "/foo/bar/*.jsp"?
2. What principal difference between '/*' and '/'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use less restrictive pattern (for example, `/foo/bar/*`) and apply additional restrictions programmatically.
2. `/` handles request only if its URL doesn't match any other mapping, whereas `/*` follows normal mapping precendence rules.
   For example, if you map front controller of your application as `/*` you won't be able to render JSP pages, because `/*` takes precendence over built-in JSP servlet mapped to `*.jsp`.

Comment: Which document defines the mentioned precedence?